# I can't find my Visual Studio 2015 Community edition executable

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I am running windows. I have three different kinds of Visual Studios, Ultimate 2013, Community 2015 and Enterprise 2015.

When I go to the list in control panel > Uninstall a program, I can see that I have Community 2015 installed but I don't know where the executable is.

I have read in a previous question that it's under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE` but the only executable I find there is `devenv.exe` and it's for the enterprise version, not the community version.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's the same executable (devenv.exe), I ran into the issue where my Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 license expired and couldn't "find" the community version. I uninstalled Enterprise via the command line (vs_enterprise.exe /uninstall /force) then ran devenv.exe /ResetSkipPkgs and am now running community no problem!